# cannot implicitly convert expression e of type main.T to main.main.T

Tags: d

What does the double `main` mean? Are there two nested levels of `main` scope somehow?

```
Error: cannot implicitly convert expression myFunction(f) of type main.M!(Tuple!(wstring, wstring)*) to main.main.M!(Tuple!(wstring, wstring)*)
```

The only difference is `main.main` instead of `main`.

```
Error: cannot implicitly convert expression myFunction(f) of type 
     main.M!(Tuple!(wstring, wstring)*)
to
main.main.M!(Tuple!(wstring, wstring)*)
```

Context:

- `M` is a struct defined at the top level
- the call to `myFunction(f)` is inside a delegate literal that is immediately called; something like `(delegate bool () {myFunction(f);return true;})()`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had two copies of the struct definition.

1. M struct definition
2. definition of `myFunction` which returns values of type M
3. M struct definition, again
4. `M = myFunction(f);`

thus we have a type mismatch, since the two `M`'s are actually different types, but under the same name